# Elasticsearch is limited to 10,000 results

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, scroll

I am using nodejs and querying in elasticsearch. I want the output that matches the conditions. But, I am not able to output more than 10,000 records because of max_result_window setting in elastic search which is defaulted to 10,000 in elastic search.

On googling how to get more than 10,000 records, I found 2 methods :
1. To use :
`curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my_index/_settings" -d '{ "index" : { "max_result_window" : 500000 } }'`
I am not able to run the above command. Can someone say a method to run the above in nodejs.

2. To use scroll method :
   Here, I am able to set time limit like say 1m, but I am not able to access the successive records using _scrollid.

Comment: *not able to access the successive records using _scrollid* What did you try, what error did you get?

Comment: client.search/scroll=1m
{
    "size": 10000,
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "title" : "elasticsearch"
        }
    }
}
client.search/scroll 
{
    "scroll" : "1m", 
    "scroll_id" : "DXF1ZXJ5QW5kRmV0Y2gBAAAAAAAAAD4WYm9laVYtZndUQlNsdDcwakFMNjU1QQ==" 
}